# Produce a list of people that have more than one item

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table of people...

```
person:
-----------
id | person
---+-------
 1 | Jim
 2 | Bob
 3 | Frank
```

...and I have a table of items...

```
item:
----------------
id | item | type
---+------+-----
 1 |   21 |    2
 2 |   10 |    5
 3 |   11 |    1
 4 |    9 |    1
```

...and I also have a table describing who has what...

```
person_item:
-------------
item | person
-----+-------
   1 |      2
   2 |      1
   3 |      1
```

How can I create a single query that will tell me when an individual has more than one item of a particular type? I only want the query to concern itself with items of type (1, 2, 3).

The results from the query should be in the following format:

```
---------------
person  |  item
        |  item
--------+------
person  |  item
        |  item
        |  item
--------+------
... etc.
```

This is what I have tried... but it produces garbage...

```
SELECT person.id, item.id FROM person_item AS pi
JOIN item AS i ON i.id = pi.item
JOIN person AS p ON p.id = pi.item
WHERE item.type IN (1,2,3)
HAVING COUNT(pi.person) > 1;
```

Comment: Define Garbage. An error?

Comment: It pulls one row, and I know for a fact there are at least 3 such people in my database. Interestingly, that row is correct... but there should be more.

Comment: Your join to person should be on `p.id = pi.person`.

Answer (score 1):

The query is suspect because you have a `having` clause but not a `group by` clause.  Also, you are using table names when you have very reasonable aliases.  And, you want to count distinct items within a person/type combination, not just for a person.

Taking these into account, try this query:

```
SELECT p.id, i.type, group_concat(i.item) as items
FROM person_item pi join
     item i
     ON i.id = pi.item join
     person p
     ON p.id = pi.person
WHERE i.type IN (1,2,3)
group by p.id, i.type
HAVING COUNT(distinct i.id) > 1;
```

This also provides the list of items as the third things returned.

Comment: Yeah, my example was a little off because I had to over-simplify, and change table/column names to something easily understood. But thanks, I will try this out.

Comment: +1 Yet another case of mysql grouping Kung fu causing havoc for novices. Mysql should have made the syntax GROUP BY ONLY ... Or similar, and required a HAVING to have a GROUP BY or imply a proper group by or something.

Comment: 1. I'm not a novice... just a bit out of practice, and I need this done quickly; 2. The answer isn't quite correct, as it's GROUPing on person, which it should allow for multiples. But, I can take it from here...

Comment: @GordonFreeman . . . This query should be answering the question:  "How can I create a single query that will tell me when an individual has more than one item of a particular type? ".  It does so by returning a row for each person/item type that has more than one item.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to see person and item id's, you don't need to join to `person` - just access person_item (with a link to item for item_type). However, if you want each combination on a separate line, you will have to access person_item twice - like so:

```
select pi.person, pi.item
from person_item pi
join (select p.person
      from person_item p
      join item i on p.item = i.item_id and i.type in (1,2,3)
      group by p.person
      having count(*) > 1) c
  on pi.person = c.person
```